# Flex : How can I get the audio stream on server side(tomcat)?

Tags: java, apache-flex

One of my web applications have developed in java and using tomcat server. Now I want add one more feature in my application that is peer to peer audio streaming. Actually I want that anyone speak (using microphone) on the client side and I will hear his voice on my server speakers and vice versa. Also save our communication in any file and also send the audio stream to IP intercom.

For that I am trying to use Flex Builder. Flex NetStream class is good for the streaming and we can also attached microphone.  But the problem is on the server side. How can I get the audio stream on server side?

Or any other idea how can I get stream from server to client and vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do this would just be to run another client on your server.   Maybe even a "special client".

Comment: ok if i open client on my machine still server is in middle. Client send bytes to the server and server send to the other client.